# I Can't Open Privet Network On METAMASK

Tags: truffle, testrpc, metamask

when i want open PRIVET NETWORK on METAMASK it wont open.
i try it in two PC on same local ethernet

Comment: Salam Taha, would you please edit your question and provide more details about your problem?

Comment: What client are you running your private network on?

Comment: check it for make better questions https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask , you provided us 0 details about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be a problem with testrpc, potentially it can't listen on the localhost:8545 for different reasons (firewall, another process listening on the same port,etc..).
**Solution** :
 restart it and check if the port is already open :
 `netstat -aon | find /i "listening" | find "8545" // for windows`

```
netstat -na | grep -i LISTEN | grep 8545 // for linux
```

otherwise run it and specify different port using `--port`

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a lot of people recently have trouble connecting to private networks where the `chainId` is not equal to the `networkId`. Consult your private network's manual for how to make sure its `chainId` and `networkId` are both the same, unique number.

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: It depends what client you're using, you can refer to the client's documentation for how.